# Plotting Intersecting 3D Regions in Maple

Tags: maple

I am brand spanking new to Maple (just downloaded tonight) and I'm also taking a course in multivariable Calculus. One of the reasons I downloaded Maple was because I'm having an extremely difficult time visualizing some of my problems in three dimensions.

A lot of my homework problems center around a region being bound by something like a parabolic cylinder, a plane, and maybe something like the xy-plane. In other situations, it's the intersection of two parabolic cylinders or something like that.

This is an example of one of my problems:

*Find the volume of the wedge-shaped region contained in the cylinder* $$x^2 + y^2 = 16$$ *and bounded above by the plane* $$z=x$$ *and below by the xy-plane.*

I'm not looking for how to solve the problem (I already have) I would just like to know how to graph the "wedge" and only the wedge using Maple. I would greatly appreciate any help or insight!

Answer (score 2):

Did you meant something like this?

```
plot3d(x, x=0..sqrt(16-y^2), y=-4..4, filled=true,
       style=patchnogrid, labels=["x","y","z"]);
```

[image]

Comment: Yep! That's exactly what I was trying to do! Thank you! I up voted your answer but I need more reputation to do that, I suppose.

Comment: You can still toggle the answer as being accepted (green check mark), I believe. No pressure. No worries. p.s. www.mapleprimes.com or stackoverflow is more suitable for Maple programming questions that are not primarily about the math.